# How to make mail messages use the UTF8 character encoding?

Tags: 7, emails

I am sending mails to users about products, using the [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) and [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) modules. I set UTF8 as charset in the mail header, but the header is changed from UTF8 to multipart on this line in the mail.inc file:

```
$message = $system->format($message);
```

It actually changes the Swedish characters to some strange characters. So that's the problem: I can't display them correctly.

Any suggestions to correctly display them?

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Type: multipart/alternative;` means that there are parts that can have their own encoding set. If your mail sending modules decide they need multipart, mail should be formatted like that:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundary

--boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

This part uses UTF-8.
--boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

This part uses ISO 8859-1.
--boundary--
```

[code sample source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147155)

If you called everything the way module docs tells you to, and UTF-8 data is not in the UTF-8 part, then you just found a bug in one of your modules.

Comment: Can't say more without a full code.

Comment: These are the headers that I use. <code>  $headers = array(
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format = flowed;',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
  );

  foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
      $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
  }
</code>

Comment: Given the information the question contains, this is a plausible answer, and hits the point. Setting _multipart/alternative_ as content type doesn't conflict with setting the charset. That means that or a module contains a bug, or a module has not been correctly configured.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can also create this functionality using custom hooks.

```
function add_newsletter() {
 $news_query = db_insert('news_letter')
        ->fields(array(
            'email_id' => $_POST['email'],
            'created' => REQUEST_TIME))
        ->execute();
if($news_query) {
    echo '1';
}else {
    echo '0';
}

$to = "abc_example@gmail.com";
$subject  = 'Mail coming from Subscribe';
$message  = "Hi, please check the below email coming from User Subscribers. User Email Id is : ".$_POST['email'];
$headers  = 'From: '.$_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    echo "Email sent successfully";
else
    echo "Email sending failed";
}
```